# What hreflang value, should I use for country selectors?

Tags: seo, local-seo

So our website supports 3 different languages (RU, EN and LT),

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="lt" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://en.example.com/" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://ru.example.com/" hreflang="ru" />
```

None of these variations are region specific, do my understanding is that as long as these are in every page, it will do the job?

What I want to clarify though, is part with language selectors, we have 3 links like so:

```
<a href="http://ru.example.com/" rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" title="RU">RU</a>
<a href="http://en.example.com/" rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" title="EN">EN</a>
<a href="http://example.com/" rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" title="LT">LT</a>
```

Did I use **hreflang** attribute correctly in this scenario? Or does it somehow need to reference the **link** tags in the header somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  have a three language versions of a URL: in this case, each language page must identify the two other language versions, including itself.  So **on each language version page** you  need to do this:

> ```
>  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://en.example.com/" />
>  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru" href="http://ru.example.com/" />
>  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="lt" href="http://lt.example.com/" />
> ```

(*[source](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en)*)

For the second snippet you shared, it is not useful for you as you already stated your web page is not region specific. However, I want to fix a small error with your code snippet in case your web page was region specific:

The design is that you need to build 3 language web pages which are region specific plus you add a fourth custom web page for visitors who do not belong to any of those 3 regions. In addition, you'll have to specify the region ([ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)) in this case. On your custom web page you need to display the language selector.

(*[source](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fi/2013/04/x-default-hreflang-for-international-pages.html)*)

Answer (score 1):

Language selectors, which, if i understand you correctly, are placed in the `body`, don't need `rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default"` constructions. Such are only for the `head`.

Your snippet

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="lt" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://en.example.com/" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://ru.example.com/" hreflang="ru" />
```

is correct for sites with the same content in different languages.